# How to pass a parameter to url from controller using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing add and edit in 1 page. Listing is showing below in a table. From the list while I click on edit button, I want to pass the id of that item in url. So that if accidentally page is being refreshed, the data will remain in the edit form. And also I am using nested view(eg: settings.couriers)
My html

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editCourier({id: x.id})">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </button>
```

My controller.js to edit

```js
$scope.editCourier = function(id, index) {
        $.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url':'settings/editCourier',
            'data': 'id='+id, 
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) { 
                $scope.formData = data[0];                
            }
        });     
    }
```

Is there any way out. please help. Thank you

Comment: my edit is working fine. But I want to pass the id as url parameter. So that if ever I refresh the page the value will remain intact in the inputbox

Comment: So this is not a SPA with some routing etc but you still want to affect the url just in case an unwanted page-refresh happens while the edit form is shown?

Comment: To be more specific my url is :http://localhost/myproject/#/staffs/add_staff?id=52. How can I get id value in my controller. I have tried $stateParams.id.

Comment: Are you getting click id inside editCourier () function??

Comment: No I am not getting id in controller

Comment: x.id in that x is from ng-repeat??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my HTML to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editCourier(index)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                    </button>
```

I have changed my controller function.

```
$scope.editCourier = function(index) {
        $.ajax({
            'type': "POST",
            'async': false,
            'global': false,
            'url':'settings/editCourier',
            'data': 'id='+ $stateParams.id, 
            'dataType': "json",
            'success': function (data) { 
                $scope.formData = data[0];   
                $scope.couriers.splice(index, 1);
                $state.go('statename', {id: $stateParams.id}, {reload: true});             
            }
        });     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editCourier({id: x.id})">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

to:

```
<a href="/editCourier/id" />
```

and in the controller, get the Id using Angular's RouteParams. 
Refer to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass id to Function  editCourier(x.id)

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editCourier(x.id)">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </button>
```

And In Controller

```
  $scope.editCourier = function(id, index) {
       console.log(id);//Check here whether the click id is coming or not
}
```